# ¿Como cambiar el nombre de la cookie que me crea el token en los formularios?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, tokens

Tengo un formulario en donde ocupo `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` el cual me crea una `cookie` de nombre `__RequestVerificationToken` la cual quiero ocultar. Para ello pensaba en cambiar el nombre de esa `cookie` a otro para no hacer tan evidente que es de ASP.NET o que es el token de autorización de formularios.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar con esto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vamos por partes, primero al archivo: `global.asax.cs`

```
public void Application_Start()
{

....
AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName = "__ElNombreQueDeseesComoToken";
...

}
```

Para evitar lios, problemas, jaleos o como quieran llamarlo, vamos a crear un Html Helper

```
public static MvcHtmlString myAntiForgeryToken(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    return new MvcHtmlString(AntiForgery.GetHtml().ToString().Replace("__RequestVerificationToken", AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName));
}
```

Para evitar confusiones, crearemos un nuevo `attribute`, de tal manera que podemos "decorar" a los controladores para hacerlos seguros, dicho sea de paso, utilizarán el nuevo nombre de la cookie.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace myNamespace
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class myValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute :
    FilterAttribute,
    IAuthorizationFilter
    {

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
            }

            try
            {
                var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
                var cookie = httpContext.Request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];
                AntiForgery.Validate(cookie != null ? cookie.Value : null, httpContext.Request.Form[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName]);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Para cerrar con broche de oro, a cada controlador donde hayas utilizado el gran e ilustre `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` debes cambiarlo al nuevo atributo `[myValidateAntiForgeryToken]` y en cada vista donde hayas usado `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` lo reemplazas por un `@Html.myAntiForgeryToken()`

Comment: ¿Osea si o si es necesario crear todo desde cero? me refiero al decorador y al html helpers

Comment: Así es. Por curiosidad, ¿esperabas que sea menos código?

Comment: No, pero no esperaba que habria que hacer nuevamente lo que ya existía.